# Display static data in html page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamically changing mysql table(issuelist) with columns issueno.,issuetime and status. I display only issues with certain status(bad) in a html page.

```
"select issueno.,status from issuelist where status='bad' group by issueno.;"
```

Now I want to make the webpage static from Sunday to next Sunday, i.e., if the status of an issue changes from bad to good on `tuesday`, even then I want the page to display that particular issue with `status = bad` till `next Sunday`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: @what you have tried?

Comment: is this part of your real code `select issueno.` and `group by issueno.` with the dot. You realize this should be throwing you an error.

Comment: No.. i framed this example to simplify the problem explanation...

Comment: Till now...the html page is dynamically changing...i am looking for some solution without altering the table....

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data somewhere in your database (for example you could add a column fixdate that would be NULL for issues with status that was good from the beggining or the date of the fix for the issues that changed status. That way, you could specify a static date to compare with the fixdate then show 'bad' or 'good' depending on the case.

Also you don't need to GROUP BY in a single table query with no operation